# how to combine results of query and return that result using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i am new with codeigniter.
i have used the following code to execute query recursively.

Suppose $q query select 4 id (10,11,20,24)

then for each id  showreply function (in foreach) call recursively then how can return the combine result.

```
$resultq3 = $this->showreply($reply_id); 

    <?php
            public function showreply($reply_id)
            {

                   $q1 =$this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('forum_reply AS fr')
                ->where('fr.parent_id',$reply_id1)
                ->order_by('fr.id ')->get();;


                foreach($q1->result_array() as $row4)
                {
                    $id = $row4['id'];  
                    $parent_id = $row4['parent_id'];
                    if($parent_id!=0)
                    {  
                        $this->showreply($id);                       

                    }
                }
                return  $result;
            }
         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding what it is you're asking here. Maybe showing the showReply function would help, but you already have the combined result and are splitting that out in your foreach so what's the problem? Also why are you assigning reply_id to reply_id1? What is the point of that? Just use $reply_id in your query.

You're also executing an if statement that makes little sense since you can filter out the id's you don't want in the query itself (and are you seriously ever going to have an id that = 0?)

In fact the more I look at this code the more confused I become. Where is $id getting populated for $this->showreply($id)?

```
<?php
    public function showreply($reply_id)
    {

        $q1 =$this->db->select('*')
            ->from('forum_reply AS fr')
        ->where('fr.parent_id',$reply_id)
        ->where('fr.parent_id !=',0)
        ->order_by('fr.id ')->get();;

        //$i=0;
        foreach($q1->result_array() as $row4)
        { 
            $parent_id = $row4['parent_id'];
            $this->showreply($id);      
        }
//below is the actual answer to your question on how to return the combined results.
        return  $q1->result_array();
    }
 ?>
```

Okay after rereading your question I think I have a better understanding. If you pass the id's as an array like this:

```
$reply_id =  array(10,11,20,24);
```

You can then modify your query to use:

```
$this->db->where_in('fr.parent_id', $reply_id);
```

That will return the results as one combined result with all 4 ids included.

Comment: :sorry,i have missed to write id in foreach.now in for each each time new query is executing now i want to return result of all query in single array.